# nil error when accessing IBOutlet connected to storyboard in viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to add a header to my table view (not the section header). But for some reasons(I don't know what it is), after dragging a UIView to table view and then running the app, the header still can not appear in my app.

So I try to add it in my code. Here's the problem, after running this app, it will stop and report a fatal error:Fatal error: "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value".

I'm sure that I build a connection between my code and storyboard, because the circle next to my IBOutlet is solid, and I can see the connection in my storyboard. It's in viewDidLoad(), so I think the views have already been loaded?

Xcode 12.5, swift 5

I don't know why, can somebody help me?

p.s: I've tried clean but it didn't work.

p.p.s: Sorry I tagged a wrong flag matches the position where error happens. I've corrected in my code. Thank u!

Here's my code.

```
    import UIKit

class ItemsViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var addButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var editButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var headerView: UIView!
    
    @IBAction func addNewItem(_ sender: UIButton){
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func toggleEditingMode(_ sender: UIButton){
        // ...
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
       // ...
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        // ...
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView 
headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red // error here
tableView.tableHeaderView?.addSubview(editButton) 
        tableView.tableHeaderView?.addSubview(addButton)
        tableView.tableHeaderView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the class name of 'headerView' really `UIView`?

Comment: Hi @ElTomato, I think it is. In the code, as you can see, it is `UIView`. And in the storyboard, I just dragged a "View" into the table view. So I think it is.

Comment: I don't use `UITableViewController`.  So try the following if you like instead of 'tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView'.  let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: view.frame.width, height: 30.0);
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange;
tableView.tableHeaderView = myView

Comment: Actually, try setting headerView to the table view under `viewWillAppear`,  `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

Comment: If I new a `UIView` like you said `'tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView'. let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: view.frame.width, height: 30.0); myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange;`, it does work!

Comment: That means your table view controller has no access to headerView under `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: And I tried setting headerView under `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, it still report the same error. And why my table vc has no access to headerView under viewDidLoad?

Comment: I don't use `UITableViewController` or `UICollectionViewController`.  So I have no answer for that.  Plus, I usually add a `UIView` object like the orange guy to the table view header programmatically.  Maybe, that's what you should do.  But I am not sure.

Comment: Quick question: If you add beforehand in `viewDidLoad()`, `print(addButton)` does it still crash?

Comment: Hi @Larme, I made a correction in my Question TAT. I've tagged a wrong position where error happens. You can check it if you like. And I tried `print(addButton)`, it prints `nil` in the console and yes it still crash

Comment: Did you do at some point: `ItemsViewController()` ? `ItemsViewController.init()`? How does `ItemsViewController` "appears" on your app? A `segue`?

Comment: @Larme you are right. I do use ItemsViewController() in a class called `SceneDelegate` which I use to inject a data source to my table view controller. Thank you veryyyyyyy much!

Comment: Your iboutlet is connected with a storyboard. But if you just do init(), how is it supposed to know to load it with that storyboard? That’s the issue. See how to init a Vc from a storyboard and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will see it carefully ; ) @Larme

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you have connected the `@IBOutlet`s correctly, make sure that you are using [`UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller) to instantiate your view controller.

If you don't use above method, your storyboard layout won't be linked to your view controller instance.

Comment: I don't add my custom init(). Does it mean I'm using 
 `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` to instantiate my view controller?